# Is qputenv thread safe?

Tags: linux, qt, environment-variables

The libc documentation says that

> Modifications of environment variables are not allowed in multi-threaded programs. The getenv and secure_getenv functions can be safely used in multi-threaded programs.
> [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Access.html#Environment-Access)

In Qt5.15 the documentation for `qgetenv` says

> The Qt environment manipulation functions are thread-safe, but this requires that the C library equivalent functions like getenv and putenv are not directly called.
> [...]
> Note: This function is thread-safe.
> [source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtenvironmentvariables-qtcore-proxy.html#qgetenv)

However the documentation for `qputenv` says

> Note: qputenv() was introduced because putenv() from the standard C library was deprecated in VC2005 (and later versions). qputenv() uses the replacement function in VC, and calls the standard C library's implementation on all other platforms. [source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtenvironmentvariables-qtcore-proxy.html#qputenv)

So it looks to me like, on Linux, `qputenv` calls `putenv`, which would not be thread-safe. To me, this seems to contradict the docs for `qgetenv` saying "The Qt environment manipulation functions are thread-safe." What am I missing? Is there a thread-safe way to set an environment variable in Qt 5.15? Thanks!

Comment: For some further information, I started wondering about this after reading [this blog post](https://rachelbythebay.com/w/2017/01/30/env/) about thread safety of environment variables.

Comment: I looked at the implementation of `qputenv`, found [here](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/72ee1df260d728a1e699bd4c6e03bf202c929cbd/src/corelib/global/qtenvironmentvariables.cpp#L268). It uses a mutex to protect calls to the Qt functions that interact with environment vars. My conclusion: "qputenv is thread safe if all access of environment variables in your program happens through the Qt functions. However, it's hard to know whether that's true, since third-party code you call could call getenv, so it's best not to modify environment variables once you've got multiple threads going."

Comment: I suggest to include all the above to your question, or, if you consider it a valid (even though not "definitive") answer, add it as such using the related answer field of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, qputenv and qgetenv are thread-safe insofar that they don't race each other. But nothing can make them thread-safe with a direct call to putenv, since that function and the data it manipulates just isn't thread-safe. And then qputenv isn't magically thread-safe with direct calls to getenv, either.